# ASP.NET MVC 2 with .NET 3.5 on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, iis-6, wildcard

Good day to you,

I would like to ask you one question that has been my major problem in past few days. I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. Server runs IIS 6 with wildcard mapping enabled. It works when I'm displaying home page. But when I click a link to navigate me to other pages i get 404 exception. Server runs .net 3.5 SP1 . I don't know where I'm making a mistake . Please help me . Thank you for your answers.

Comment: post your route setup and URL you cannot get to

Comment: Make sure, in case you're on a 64 bits server, when selecting the aspnet_isapi.dll, to do it from the correct directory, i.e. c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you also cleared the 'check that file exists?' checkbox on your wildcard mapping?

[image: Wilcard configuration "Check that file exists"]