# The page cannot be found...most of the time

Tags: sql, iis, dotnetnuke

We have an old version of DNN running as our production website (version 04.09.00).  My manager is fearful of upgrading to a newer version because of the customization done to the code before I started with the company.  In any event, we need to spawn another copy of the same side on a dev server (staging.website.com) and I seem to be running into issues.

As far as I can tell, IIS is set up correctly.  I made a copy of the production database and production file system and moved it over the the dev server.  I changed the portal alias in the DB to match the staging URL and changed the host setting similarily.  I edited the connection string to reflect the new server and db name.  I even searched the file folders for any reference to www.website.com and replaced them with staging.website.com.

Then I went to the staging site.  It looked great!  It looked just like production...until I clicked on a link.  It looks like the home page is the only one that will work, every other page I've tried (and I've tried a bunch) come up with the same "The page cannot be found" error.  I know it's hitting the database because all the dynamic data and configurations from production is showing up.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I wondered if it was the [wildcard script mapping 'check that file exists'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874806/243245) but on reflection that's probably not it. Have you compared all the IIS settings between the two, though?

Comment: Yep, I opened both property windows side-by-side in IIS and went tab-by-tab.  They're virtually identical.

Comment: And I did doublecheck.  They are using the same dll for wildcard mapping with "check that file exists" turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that worked (for some reason).  I deleted the website in IIS and recreated it.  That seems to have done the trick.  Not sure what the first website was holding onto but clearing that out and starting over again was all it took.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

On the older versions of DNN you need to manually add the PortalAlias to the PortalAlias table to ensure that the site works properly.  So I would start by looking at the values in that table for the HttpAlias column and update as needed.

From there, if you are using something like iFinity UrlMaster and are removing page extensions (IE your url;s don't have a .aspx extension) ensure that if you are on IIS 6 that you have a wildcard mapping setup, or if you are on IIS 7 that you are running in Integrated Pipeline mode.

Comment: The only entry I have in PortalAlias is PortalAliasID = 4 PortalID = 3 and HTTPAlias = staging.website.com next I have varified that portal 3 exists in the portals table.

Comment: UrlMaster is running flawlessly on production and this is the same code, database and iis version for staging.  I did go through http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/KB/Url_Master/topic/Manually+Removing+the+Url+Master+module+configurat in an attempt to disable UrlMaster but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: I just checked wildcard mapping.  There is an entry for both production and staging for v2.0.50727/aspnet_isapi.dll and nothing else.  So they have the same wildcard mapping dll.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on those links are the URLs different?

Are you using a custom URL Provider like IFinity's FriendlyUrlProvider?

I would also check to see what Menu is being used in your skin, it is possible that the menu is causing a problem if it requires a custom configuration.

Comment: iFinity is installed but from what I can tell, I've disabled it in the webconfig.  I do have a post over at iFinity as well.